Sharepoint Lists - Column Formatting - List View v Calendar View
I am creating a list for my team.
There are five members.
I have created a Responsibility column - person type
Working in the List View:
For the Title Column, I have created a column formatting rule for each person
If Responsiblity = "person", then fill the Title column with 'choice of colour' from built in selections (different colour for each person)
if Responsibility = "", then "no styles"
the formatting rules do not carry over to the Calendar view.
So I tried to recreate similar column formatting rules for the Calendar view,
but I am not given the "no styles" option
Is there any way to access "no styles" in the Calendar View column formatting?
If I look at the JSON programming for the Calendar view, then I do not see how the default colour set.
If I could see how it was set, then I should be able to set it to no colour.
